# How to get entry file raw source code before creating modules in Webpack Plugin API

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, plugins

## Question

I'm trying to inject code into a specific entry point **before** webpack creates modules out of it. This code is generated in node before the bundle is created. Here are the specifics:

- I don't want to manipulate the entry file, but rather manipulate the raw source in memory before webpack does its magic.
- I also need to pass options in from somewhere.

## Stuff I've tried

#### => Create a loader

This is by far the easiest way to do it. Import a file that's targeted in the webpack config, and have the loader do the injecting. Example:

```
{
  test: /\.custom-file$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'my-loader',
    options: {},
  },
}
```

The problem with this is that I'd need to have an arbitrary file (`.custom-file`) laying around in my repo with **nothing** in it, just so webpack has something to import...

You could import "nothing" by using the inline loader syntax and purposefully leaving out a file to import:

```
import myContent from '!my-loader';
```

This works, but it requires you to write your entire config inline as well. The config I would need is a bit too verbose to use this method...

#### => Create a plugin

After reading (what seemed to be) all of the plugin tutorials on the internet, I'm convinced that there's **gotta** be a way to use a plugin to gain access to the entry file source code.

I feel like i've checked every hook and the closest I can get is the `normalModuleFactory`, but looking through that output, I can't seem to find the source of the entry files...

Comment: Hi @geoctrl, did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up using this webpack plugin:

https://github.com/adierkens/webpack-inject-plugin

the plugin creates a webpack loader on the fly and injects your code into the entry files you specify.